# How Can I insert multiple list values into mysql column from hibernate jpa with data.sql?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database, hibernate

Im trying to create a api that looks similar to this:

[image]

So ive this etiquetas "tags" field where ive to insert multiple values (languages) that the expert knows.

ive stablished a many to many relationship between tags and experts like this way:

expert model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="experts")
public class Expert {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String dni;
    private String address;
    private String mail;
    private String phone;
    private String created_at;
    private String updated_at;
    private String linkedln;
    private String state;
    private String rating;
    private String availability;



    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="expert", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

//constructor, getters and setters
```

tag model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "experts_tags",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="expert_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private List<Expert> expert = new ArrayList<>();

    public Tag() {
    }
    //getters and setters
```

So ive tried to insert multiple tags into my expert column this way:

experts(name,surname,dni,address,mail,phone,created_at,updated_at,linkedln,state,rating,availability, tags)
values('Peter', 'Robinson','172382193D', 'calle del pino,n 2, león','peter@robinson.com','6768292394',
'15/04/2021', '16/05/2021','https://www.linkedin.com/in/sara-b-54b93543/', 'validado', '100','tardes','{php,java,spring}');

However the tags field is not recognized and appear a mysql sintax error.

So How can I add succesfuly tag values so they appear in my api?

Thanks I appreciate any help!

Comment: There is no `tags` column in the table. `Tag` is a separate entity, with its own table. You need to insert `tags` into the `tags` table and establish the association between `Tag`s and `Expert`s by inserting their corresponding ids into the `experts_tags` table

Comment: have sense, thank you very much, ill try